# How to modify ggplot2 legend_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use

```
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(ClusterID)))
```

but I want to get `ClusterID` visible without the word `factor`.

**How can I modify the legend title in ggplot2?**

[image]

Comment: Define it as a factor before plotting, would probably be easiest. Also, see here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to do the factor conversion before plotting. For example using `dplyr`, assuming data frame `mydata` and variables `x, y`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
  mutate(ClusterID = factor(ClusterID)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(color = ClusterID))
```

Another option is to name the legend in `scale_color_discrete`:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(ClusterID))) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "ClusterID")
```